# Set a value in an array within a class

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and I'm not really familiar with classes, my question is how can I get the value of ***$quantity*** and pass it to public array which is within a class? My expected array output would be Bag => 10.

Here's my code:

```
$quantity = 10;

class QuantityLeft{

    public array $inventory = [ 

        'Bag' => [$quantity value here]

    ];

}
```

Comment: You write a setter-method to pass the value...

Comment: try to use `global`

Comment: Either make it procedural or make it OOP based. Don't mix both

Comment: `global` should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: provide the value through class constructor.

Option 2: Write a setter method and call it on the object

Below example implements both. The member variable should be protected against direct modification, and the setter makes validation of the input parameter to avoid illegal values.

```
class QuantityLeft {
    protected $inventory = [];

    public function __construct($quantity) {
        $this->setQuantity($quantity);
    }

    public function setQuantity($quantity) {
        if ($quantity < 0) {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException('Quantity must be greater or equal 0');
        }
        $this->inventory['Bag'] = $quantity;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj = new QuantityLeft(50);
```

or

```
$obj = new QuantityLeft(0);
$obj->setQuantity(50);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
global $quantity =10
```

and than:

```
class QuantityLeft{

public array $inventory = [ 

    'Bag' => global $quantity

];

}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).